# How to refer java variable length arguments in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I can refer `String` in kotlin as `String::class.java` but how to refer `String...`?

I need to use it to test a private method

```
private void someMethod(int a, int b, String... c) {
   . . .
}
```

```
val method: Method = SomeActivity::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
            "someMethod",
            Int::class.java,
            Int::class.java,
            {{need help here}}
        )
method.isAccessible = true
method.invoke(activity, 0, 0, "")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can refer to it easily using `Array<String>::class.java`

```
val method: Method = SomeActivity::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
            "someMethod",
            Int::class.java,
            Int::class.java,
            Array<String>::class.java
        )
method.isAccessible = true
method.invoke(activity, 0, 0, arrayOf(""))
```